# how to serialize StrokeCollection in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, memorystream, binaryformatter

i want to save a Stroke in a memorystream 
for this purpose is used BinaryFormatter but when i try to serialize Stroke i get a error that i can't serialize Stroke

is there any way to save a Stroke in a memorystream or serialize Stroke?

here is one part of my code

```
int size = inkCanvas1.Strokes.Count();
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        if (size != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, inkCanvas1.Strokes[size - 1]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: What for type is StrokeCollection?

Comment: You could try to [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590544) with [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)

Comment: If you MENTIONING that you've got an ERROR, please SHOW the exact error and/or stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work is that `StrokeCollection` doesn't have the [`SerializableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) applied.

But you can use the [`StrokeCollection.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ink.strokecollection.save.aspx) method for this.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (ms)
{
    StrokeCollection sc = ...;
    sc.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
}
```

And then when you need the `StrokeCollection` again, you can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522846) that accepts a `Stream`.

Comment: Why is the `using (ms)` helpful? I've seen things like `using(var ms = new MemoryStream())`, and I understand that's so it gets garbage collected immediately after use, or even if exceptions happen, but here it's instantiated outside the `using`?

Comment: The only thing the `using` statement does is make sure the `Dispose` method of the resource is called (even in the case of exceptions). I could just as well have used `using (var ms = new MemoryStream())`, this is exactly the same.